# Can I build my own modals in/for DataTables + Editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with DataTables, the plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library and its extension Editor . Because my table got over 20 columns my modals for creating and editing entries are looking really confusing because of these many fields.

I now wanted to build my own bootstrap modal, because I can't really array the fields in the Datatable-modal. My question is, whether I'm able to link the fields and buttons of my own modal to the editor-instance and its actions (especially the save-action).

I build a little example-modal with three columns [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yaksey/3fs7erf4/).

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Demo Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Label</label>
                    <input style="width:100px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Label</label>
                    <input style="width:100px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Label</label>
                    <input style="width:100px;">
                </div>
            </div> 
           […]
```